# How to set default value for record type on visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Case" tabStyle="Case" lightningstylesheets="true" extensions="CaseController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Clone Sample Request" subtitle=" 
    {!CaseRecordQueried.CaseNumber}"/>
    <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" title="">
   <apex:pageblockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!cloneCase}" value="Clone" />
      <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
    </apex:pageblockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Please choose the contact on which to clone" collapsible="false">
        <apex:inputField value="{!CaseRecordQueried.RecordTypeId}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!CaseRecordQueried.ContactId}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
     <apex:pageMessages />
 </apex:page>
```

Apex controller

```
   public class Case_Controller {
 private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
 public Case CaseRecordQueried{get;set;}

 public TestCase_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     this.controller = controller;
     CaseRecordQueried = [select Id,

                    RecordTypeId
             from Case
             where id =: controller.getId()];
   }

  public PageReference cloneCase() {
     String contactid = CaseRecordQueried.ContactId;
     Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
     Case CaseCloned;
    try {
       CaseCloned = CaseRecordQueried.clone(false);
       insert CaseCloned;
       } catch (Exception e){
     Database.rollback(sp);
     ApexPages.addMessages(e);
     return null;
   }
   return new PageReference('/'+CaseCloned.id);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to display Record Type Name in VF page ?

Comment: I want to set a default value during input on VF page

Answer (score 0):

in controller class do the query for record type.

```
Case editCase = [select id, name,,RecordTypeID from case where id=:caseId];

RecordType rt = [SELECT id,DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'SOBJECT NAME' and id=:editCase.RecordTypeId];
```

set a flag for DeveloperName(RecordType name) and use the variable to pass the value with specific record type and that value you can display on vf page.

Comment: Could you demonstrate in my code, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query recordid, you need to create a record type on Case Object.

Please find below code and it's working in my ORG.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" tabStyle="Case" lightningstylesheets="true" extensions="Case_Controller">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Clone Sample Request" subtitle=" 
    {!CaseRecordQueried.CaseNumber}"/>
    <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" title="">
   <apex:pageblockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!cloneCase}" value="Clone" />
      <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
    </apex:pageblockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Please choose the contact on which to clone" collapsible="false">
        <apex:inputField value="{!CaseRecordQueried.RecordTypeId}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!CaseRecordQueried.ContactId}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
     <apex:pageMessages />
 </apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Case_Controller {
 private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
 public Case CaseRecordQueried{get;set;}

 public Case_Controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     this.controller = controller;
     CaseRecordQueried = [select Id,CaseNumber, ContactId, RecordTypeId from Case where id =: controller.getId()];
   }

  public PageReference cloneCase() {
     String contactid = CaseRecordQueried.ContactId;
     Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
     Case CaseCloned;
    try {
       CaseCloned = CaseRecordQueried.clone(false);
       insert CaseCloned;
       } catch (Exception e){
     Database.rollback(sp);
     ApexPages.addMessages(e);
     return null;
   }
   return new PageReference('/'+CaseCloned.id);
}
}
```

This is how it looks in my ORG.

[image]